# In the tetrahedron what is $XY$?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

> In tetrahedron $ABCD$, $AB = 4$, $CD = 7$, and $AC = AD = BC = BD = 5$. Let $I_A, I_B, I_C,$ and $I_D$ denote the incenters of the faces opposite vertices $A, B, C,$ and $D,$ respecitvely. It is provable that $AI_A$ intersects $BI_B$ at a point $X$, and $CI_C$ intersects $DI_D$ at a point $Y$. Compute $XY$.

<strike>Can someone provide a diagram for this question because it is hard to visualize it.</strike>

**Update** (by achille)

A diagram based on my understanding of the geometry.
[image: A tetrahedron]

- the red/green/blue arrows are $x$, $y$, $z$ axis.
- the red/green/blue/magenta line segments are $AI_A$, $BI_B$, $CI_C$ and $DI_D$.
- the black/white balls in the middle of diagram are $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Your title and text contain two different questions. Do you want an answer to the original question, to compute $XY$, or do you just want a diagram?

Comment: If you want the value of $XY$, is an approximation good enough?

Comment: @RoryDaulton since I added a diagram for OP, we only need to compute $XY$ now.

Comment: We must have the exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = 4$, $v = 7$ and $w = 5$.

To attack this problem, the key is $AC = AD = BC = BD$ which tell us tetrahedron $ABCD$ possesses certain symmetries.
Let $\ell$ be the line passing through the mid-point of $AB$ and the mid-point of $CD$. $ABCD$ will be invariant under

- a $180^\circ$ rotation with $\ell$ as axis.
- a mirror reflection with respect to a plane holding $AB$ and $\ell$
- a mirror reflection with respect to a plane holding $CD$ amd $\ell$.

Let $h$ be the distance between line $AB$ and $CD$. These symmetries allow us to choose a coordinate system so that $AB$ is part of the $x$-axis and $\ell$ is the $z$-axis. The vertices will be located at:

$$\begin{cases}
\vec{A} &= ( -\frac{u}{2}, 0, 0 )\\
\vec{B} &= ( +\frac{u}{2}, 0, 0 )\\
\vec{C} &= ( 0, +\frac{v}{2}, h )\\
\vec{D} &= ( 0,-\frac{v}{2}, h )
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{array}{c}
AC = AD = BC = BD = w\\
\Downarrow\\
h = \frac12\sqrt{4w^2 - u^2 - v^2}
\end{array}
$$
For a picture, please look at the one on question.
To compute the coordinates of $I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D$, we use the fact the
[Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) of the 
in-center of a triangle is proportional to the length of the sides. From this fact, we can deduce

$$
\begin{cases}
\vec{I}_A &= \frac{1}{v + 2w}\left(v \vec{B} + w(\vec{C}+\vec{D})\right)\\
\vec{I}_B &= \frac{1}{v + 2w}\left(v \vec{A} + w(\vec{C}+\vec{D})\right)\\
\vec{I}_C &= \frac{1}{u + 2w}\left(u \vec{D} + w(\vec{A}+\vec{B})\right)\\
\vec{I}_D &= \frac{1}{u + 2w}\left(u \vec{C} + w(\vec{A}+\vec{B})\right)
\end{cases}
$$
The line $AI_A$ consists of points of the form
$$
s \vec{A} + (1-s)\vec{I}_A 
= s\vec{A} + \frac{1-s}{v+2w}\left(v \vec{B} + w(\vec{C}+\vec{D})\right)\quad\text{ for some } s \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Similarly, the line $BI_B$ consists of points of the form
$$
t \vec{B} + (1-t)\vec{I}_B 
= t\vec{B} + \frac{1-t}{v+2w}\left(v \vec{A} + w(\vec{C}+\vec{D})\right)\quad\text{ for some } t \in \mathbb{R}
$$
If you compare these two expressions, it is easy to see $AI_A$ and $BI_B$ intersect at
$$\vec{X} 
= \frac{1}{2(v+w)}\left(v (\vec{A}+\vec{B}) + w (\vec{C}+\vec{D})\right) 
= \left( 0, 0, \frac{wh}{v+w} \right)$$
By a similar argument, $CI_C$ and $DI_D$ intersect at
$$\vec{Y} 
= \frac{1}{2(u+w)}\left(u (\vec{C}+\vec{D}) + w (\vec{A} + \vec{B})\right)
= \left( 0, 0, \frac{uh}{u+w} \right)$$
So the distance $XY$ we seek is given by

$$XY = \left|\frac{u}{u+w} - \frac{w}{v+w}\right|h
= \frac12\left|\frac{4}{4+5} - \frac{5}{7+5}\right|\sqrt{4\cdot 5^2 - 4^2 - 7^2}
= \frac{\sqrt{35}}{72}$$